# Fire timer only when system is awake (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, unix, cocoa, nstimer

I'm developing a mac app that makes network calls. I am using a `Timer` to make a network call every 15 mins to refresh some data. I only want the timer to fire and the call to be made when the user is using the system (otherwise it's just making unnecessary calls) aka when the system isn't asleep. How would I do this? I read about mach having a monotonic clock that only updates while the system is awake, but I'm unsure how to implement my timer to function as desired. Is there a way to determine if the system is awake? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 notifications in [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) you can use to suspend and resume the timer

- [`didWakeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530973-didwakenotification) *Posted when the machine wakes from sleep.*
- [`willSleepNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530075-willsleepnotification) *Posted before the machine goes to sleep.*
- [`screensDidSleepNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1530288-screensdidsleepnotification) *Posted when the machine’s screen goes to sleep.*
- [`screensDidWakeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1524606-screensdidwakenotification) *Posted when the machine’s screens wake.*